# Unit Test Embedded C++ Code using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, embedded

I have legacy code that I am going to refactor/add. The code is written in C++ and is targeted for embedded device using Greenhills compiler. I heard that Visual Studio 2010 has better testing framework and requires less work to write test cases. Is it possible to use VS2010 to unit test the embedded code? An Example on how to do it or stepwise procedure will be greatly appreciated.

If not, how CppUnit/CxxTest can be integrated with VS2010? I couldn't find clear documentation on how to achieve this.

Comment: I suggest starting the development project by using a small application and getting CppUnit to build with VS2010.  Once CppUnit builds, add the rest of the code.  CppUnit is easy to expand once it is built.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compile embedded software in Visual Studio.  Create stubs for platform specific functionality and also for Green Hills specifics, if any.  Also beware of any specific Green Hills macros.  You'll need to find or create equivalents.

I am using CppUnit in Visual Studio 2008 with wxWidgets.  I have not tried to integrate CppUnit with Visual Studio 2010 separately.

Keep in mind you want to keep the validation code separate from the embedded code.  The embedded code should be imported into your validation project as a library and header files.  This keeps the testing honest (although I realize that you may not be able to link a Green Hills library with a Visual Studio library).  Otherwise build the embedded code using VS, but as a separate library in the build step.

Design your testing around the Software Requirements, if possible.  After that, design some code to exercise the public functions.  Remember, the developer's should not write code to satisfy the testing, nor should the testing folks write code to satisfy the developer's functions.  "If it exists, test it."  or "If it is used, test it".  For example, the platform may have a DMA controller but not use it.

### Edit #1 -- Example

Given the following class in the "embedded" or implementation:

```
class Title
{
  public:
                                    Title();
                                    Title(const Title& rc);
    virtual                         ~Title();
    Title&                          operator= (const Title& rt);
    const std::string&              get_table_name(void) const;
    const std::string&              get_title_text(void) const;
    void                            set_table_name(const std::string&);
    void                            set_title_text(const std::string& new_text);
};
```

The CppUnit testing class would look like:

```
#include "cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h"

class Test_Ing_Title
    : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture
{
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Friends
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(Test_Ing_Title);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(ing_name_field_testing);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(copying);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(table_name_testing);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(test_id_field);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(title_testing);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(visitor_test);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Public types
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
  public:

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Public Constructors and Destructors
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
  public:
    //! Constructor - Default
                                Test_Ing_Title();

    //! Copy Constructor
                                Test_Ing_Title(const Test_Ing_Title& n_obj);

    //! Destructor
    virtual                     ~Test_Ing_Title();

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Public Overloaded Operators
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
  public:

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Public Methods
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
  public:
    //! Test cloning of the title record.
    void                        cloning(void);

    //! Test copying
    void                        copying(void);

    //! Test the name field getters and setters
    void                        ing_name_field_testing(void);

    //! Test the table name getters & setters
    void                        table_name_testing(void);

    void                        tearDown(void);

    //! Test the ID field getters and setters.
    void                        test_id_field(void);

    //! Test the title getters and setters
    void                        title_testing(void);

    //! Test visitors to the title.
    void                        visitor_test(void);
};
```

An example testing method:

```
#include <stdafx.h>     // This line is required for precompiled headers on MSVC++.
#include <cppunit/TestCase.h>
#include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>
#include <string>

void
Test_Ing_Title ::
title_testing(void)
{
    static const char           expected_title_text[] = "Ground Beef";
    const std::string           expected_title(expected_title_text);
    std::string             actual_title;
    Ingredient::Records::Title  ing_title;
    ing_title.set_title_text(expected_title);
    actual_title = ing_title.get_title_text();
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT(actual_title == expected_title);
    return;
}
```

In the above example, the test class creates an instance of the class to test, then exercises the methods.  The key point is that the test class is isolated from the system or put another way, the test class does not influence the system under test.  Placing the test code in a separate location will help emphasize this concept.  Treat the "embedded" code as read-only.  Test to the extremes, hold your ground, the reduced number of product returns will be your reward (and adds to the profit of the company).

HTH.

Comment: Thomas, Thanks much for detailed answer. One more thing, eventhough I have source code for individual class, I have to build a library and then test it using CppUnit? I was hoping that I can just add test class in VS to test my C++ implementation (just one class and dependencies). Could you provide a pointer to good getting starting tutorial? Thanks.

Comment: @Rob, see my `Edit #1`.  I haven't found a good *getting started* tutorial.  A lot of grinding on my part.  Read all of the CppUnit documentation and search the web for examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for excellent clarity in Edit #1, very helpful. I am going to try it on my code and post feedback.